# How much does SQL Server Web Edition cost? + other related questions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I visited Microsoft pricing page about SQL Server databases, but it was not that clear for me. I want to know the exact cost of SQL Server Web Edition.

Furthermore, I would like to know how can I get it if I am with VPS hosting? Should I install it by myself or will they install it for me?

And finally, is there a web host that provide SQL Server Web edition so I pay for them directly with the hosting package?

Comment: Microsoft does have a sales team you can call. Same for a number of different server hosts.

Answer (score 2):

The costs for each VPS provider will be different - that being said shop around. 
Microsoft, and a Microsoft partner are able to give you pricing - and most likely doing so here would be breaking an Acceptable Use Policy - so most will respect the rules.

One suggestion (it cannot be used for hosting however) would be for you to obtain a Microsoft Action Pack subscription (MAPS)  for $399 you can obtain a large amount of Microsoft software for next to nothing in comparison to the actual cost.

It is for development only - but that may help you while building your application(s)

There are other options as well - but MAPS is decent enough for most small shops

Comment: Is it really ok to use the MAPS software for development? I thought it was for testing only, so we actually pay for full versions in all of our development environments..

Comment: As far as I know, if you are an ISV or similar, and use the software internally, you can do that (note that per se development tools like Visual Studio are *not* include in MAPS).